# push heroku to github

Tags: git, heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt

i already have an app on Heroku that was put there by another developer.  how do i now transfer that my new github repo?

i'm already set up the empty repo on github and assigned that to the app settings on Heroku.  i just do not know how to initiate the git transfer.

i tried logging into the Heroku account from my local terminal, tho i was not able to get access--because i have two different Heroku accounts, and the email assigned to the one in this situation is not the same as what my Heroku tools is expecting on my local system.

how to do this?

Comment: have my answer been helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

Just clone the project locally and push to *Github*.

1. Look at the app settings page on *Heroku* for the proper address:

   ```
   git clone git@heroku.com:you_project.git
   ```
2. Add the origin, and just push the project into *Github*

   ```
   git add origin ...
   git push -u origin master
   ```